# Image source in WPF using icon embedded in a non referenced assembly

Tags: .net, wpf

I have found many references for using pack URIs but they all assume the assembly is referenced.  We are creating an application where using reflection we find assemblies that implement our specific interfaces.  These assemblies also have an icon as resource files inside the assembly and are located in a "plugins" directory.

This seems to work if the assemblies are in the same location as the WFP executable:
    `Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/myPlunginName;component/icon.png");`

This does not work inside the plugins directory:
    `Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/plugins/myPlunginName;component/icon.png");`

Is this even possible?  Is there a better approach we should be taking?

Answer (score 0):

If found another approach using a stream.  Now I get the embedded resource by passing a stream WPF code behind by using:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.iconName.jpg");
```

then followed the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444331/wpf-bitmapsource-imagesource).