# Set System.Windows.Controls.Image from StreamReader?

Tags: wpf, image, streamreader

I've got an image in PNG format in a StreamReader object. I want to display it on my WPF form. What's the easiest way to do that?

I've put an `Image` control on the form, but I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 2):

The `Image.Source` property requires that you supply a `BitmapSource` instance. To create this from a PNG you will need to decode it. See the related question here:

[WPF BitmapSource ImageSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444331/wpf-bitmapsource-imagesource)

```
BitmapSource source = null;

PngBitmapDecoder decoder;
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\logo.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.None);

    if (decoder.Frames != null && decoder.Frames.Count > 0)
        source = decoder.Frames[0];
}

return source;
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
 image1.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(myStreamReader.BaseStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a StreamReader, I would directly generate the Stream,

```
FileStream strm = new FileStream("myImage.png", FileMode.Open);
PngBitmapDecoder decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(strm,
    BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
myImage.Source = decoder.Frames[0];
```

where myImage is the name of your Image in XAML

```
<Image x:Name="myImage"/>
```

**Update:** If you have to use the StreamReader, you get the Stream by using .BaseStream.

Comment: Psssttt ... FileStream is IDisposable - watch out for those memory leaks ;-)

Comment: Isn't it cool after the decoder gets what it needs and the function exits?